# Matlab strsplit error

Tags: arrays, matlab, parsing, cell, strsplit

I have a variable called data that is a 5574x1 cell array. Currently, each element is an array of characters representing a sentence. I want to split each array on whitespace. So I tried doing this:

new_data = {strsplit(data{:})}

and Matlab gives me this error:

```
Error using strsplit (line 94)
Argument 'spam  Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup final tkts
21st May 2005. Text FA to 87121 to receive entry question(std txt
rate)T&C's apply 08452810075over18's' did not match any valid
parameter of the parser.
```

However, when I do this:

```
for x=1:5574
    d(x) = {strsplit(data{x})};
end
```

It works just fine. I can't seem to figure out what the difference between the two is. Why won't the first one work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I fixed my answer using strjoin to generate a single row string, as required by strsplit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `strsplit(data{:})`, it passes each cell as a different argument, but [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) needs the strings in a single argument.  Try this instead:

```
new_data = strsplit(strjoin(data))
```

**EDIT**: Use `strjoin` instead of `strvcat`.